# How to extract all matches of pattern and combine distinct matches using R?

Tags: r, string

I would like to extract all the matches from a string using a regex pattern, and then combine only the `distinct` matches into a single string.

I want to extract all the words that proceed the word `films` and then combine only the `distinct` words. I'm trying the following script, which combines all the matches:

```
text1 <- "Netflix announced 34 new Korean films to hit the streaming platform in 2023, along with 12 Japanese films. The upcoming titles, which Netflix calls their “biggest-ever lineup of Korean films and series."

pattern <- "\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b(?=\\sfilms)"

map_chr(str_extract_all(text1, pattern), paste, collapse = " | ")

> 'Korean | Japanese | Korean'
```

Desired output:

```
'Korean | Japanese'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
text1 <- "Netflix announced 34 new Korean films to hit the streaming platform in 2023, along with 12 Japanese films. The upcoming titles, which Netflix calls their “biggest-ever lineup of Korean films and series."

pattern <- "\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b(?=\\sfilms)"

paste(unique((str_extract_all(text1, pattern)[[1]])), collapse = " | ")
```

We get

```
"Korean | Japanese"
```

Comment: Hi @mohamed-desouky, Thanks for the help. I have something similar here https://ideone.com/H6FLM7. I just want to skip "as of" or "in" here

Answer (score 1):

Please unlist as done in below code and then consider the unique elements

```r
text1 <- "Netflix announced 34 new Korean films to hit the streaming platform in 2023, along with 12 Japanese films. The upcoming titles, which Netflix calls their “biggest-ever lineup of Korean films and series."

pattern <- "\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b(?=\\sfilms)"

map_chr(unique(unlist(str_extract_all(text1, pattern))), paste, collapse = " | ")
```

Comment: Nice flow @jkatam. Getting the return - `'Korean''Japanese'`